# Importing zipped CSV file into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, named-pipes, postgresql-copy

I have a big compressed csv file (25gb) and I want to import it into PostgreSQL 9.5 version. Is there any fast way to import zip or qzip file into postgres without extracting the file?

Comment: There is nothing built-in, but `copy` can get the input from a program so you could run unzip and pipe the output into the `copy` (or `\copy`) command. Some SQL clients also offer that feature

Comment: I am using pgAdmin III client which does not have option for zip file. using this `copy` command that you mentioned would be faster or extracting the file first then import into postgresql?

Comment: COPY is the command used to IMPORT and EXPORT Data from/to CSV and which doesn't have capability to extract a zip file.If you want to import using pgAdmin what you've to do is extract the zip file then use COPY to import extracted CSV file

Answer (score 24):

There is an old trick to use a named pipe (works on Unix, don't know about Windows)

- create a named pipe: `mkfifo /tmp/omyfifo`
- write the file contents to it: `zcat mycsv.csv.z > /tmp/omyfifo &`
- [from psql] `copy mytable(col1,...) from '/tmp/omyfifo'`
- [when finished] : `rm /tmp/omyfifo`

The `zcat` in the backgound will block until a reader (here: the `COPY` command) will start reading, and it will finish at EOF. (or if the reader closes the pipe)

You could even start multiple pipes+zcat pairs, which will be picked up by multiple `COPY` statements in your sql script.

---

This will work from pgadmin, but the fifo (+zcat process) should be present on the machine where the DBMS server runs.

---

BTW: a similar trick using netcat can be used to read a file from a remote machine (which of course should write the file to the network socket)

Answer (score 18):

example how to do it with `zcat` and `pipe`:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -p 5555 t -c "copy tp to '/tmp/tp.csv';"
COPY 1
-bash-4.2$ gzip /tmp/tp.csv
-bash-4.2$ zcat /tmp/tp.csv.gz | psql -p 5555 t -c "copy tp from stdin;"
COPY 1
-bash-4.2$ psql -p 5555 t -c "select count(*) from tp"
 count
-------
     2
(1 row)
```

also [from 9.3 release](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-copy.html) you can:

```
psql -p 5555 t -c "copy tp from program 'zcat /tmp/tp.csv.gz';"
```

without pipe at all

Comment: With the `program` attribute, you can move the `zcat` inside the copy command itself. 

`psql -p 5555 t -c "copy tp from program 'zcat /tmp/tp.csv.gz';"`

The ability to run programs that generate the output is independently useful. (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-copy.html)

Comment: true - `copy from stdin` requires SU anyway - so could be `copy form program`

Answer (score 3):

If you have a ZIP (.zip) instead of a GZIP (.gz) archive, you can use `unzip -p` to pipe the zipped file.

```
psql -p 5555 -t -c "copy tp from program 'unzip -p /tmp/tp.csv.zip';"
```