# Loading zipped CSV(filename.csv.gz) file into PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql

How to load larger amount of csv.gz file into Postgresql without unzipping to csv file ,since I tried pipeline command (mkfifo pipelinename) but it doesn't work for me. Is there any other solution to solve this issue ?

I have try to load it from local to postgresql using following command
command : zcat file.csv.gz | psql -U username -d database;

Result : out of memory

Need : I want to load a big size csv.gz (around 15+ GB) file from centos to postgresql database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41741644/2235885 (`didn't work for me` is not a very useful description. What exactly did you try? What went wrong? What was the error massage?)

Answer (score 7):

Note that this should also work from inside `psql`:

`\copy TABLE_NAME FROM PROGRAM 'gzip -dc FILENAME.csv.gz' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER NULL ''`

Comment: Hi @Vincent any ideas how to use it when working with multiples of gzip files?

Comment: @relayino, as @kemin-zhou pointed in another answer, you can use `zcat`, which supports multiple files.

Answer (score 4):

Just to share my simple examples using zcat instead of gzip. Simply less typing.  I am using zcat to expand the gzipped file.

```
\copy tmptable from program 'zcat O1variant.tab.gz' with (format csv, delimiter E'\t', header TRUE)
```