# Postgresql: copy from gzip + invalid byte sequence encoding

Tags: postgresql

In this post it's outlined how to copy the contents from a csv in a .gzip file into a postgresql table: [Importing zipped CSV file into PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738829/importing-zipped-csv-file-into-postgresql).

`copy tp from program 'zcat /tmp/tp.csv.gz';`

My question is whether it's possible to also convert the encoding of the csv file within the gzip, as shown here [invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867272/invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8/4867690)

so something like this:

`copy tp from program 'iconv -f original_charset -t utf-8 zcat /tmp/tp.csv.gz > stdin';`

I get the following error when applying copy from with zcat:

`psycopg2.errors.CharacterNotInRepertoire: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xba CONTEXT:  COPY tp, line 677117`

When unpacked the csv file is encoded as ASCII

`file tp.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figure out the encoding of the file, then go

```
COPY tp FROM PROGRAM 'zcat /tmp/tp.csv.gz' (ENCODING 'whatever');
```

Comment: thank you Laurenz, the following worked for me with ASCII encoding (which I read should be a subset of UTF8, nonetheless it gave an error): COPY tp FROM PROGRAM 'zcat /tmp/tp.csv.gz' (ENCODING 'latin9');